# Rafael: Mapael: Update trigger doesn't work, and no errors are given

Tags: javascript, jquery, mapael, rafaeljs

Based on [this minimal example](http://jsfiddle.net/neveldo/98xqw02n/) of Mapael (part of the relevant code is down here):

```
$('#refresh').on('click', function() {

        // Update some plots and areas attributes ...
        var updatedOptions = {'areas' : {}, 'plots' : {}};

        // add some new plots ...
        var newPlots = {
            "Dijon" : {
                latitude : 47.323056,
                longitude : 5.041944
            }
        }

        $(".mapcontainer").trigger('update', [updatedOptions, newPlots, [], {animDuration : 1000}]);
    });
```

I created [this example](https://budker.uni-mainz.de/gnome/WorldMap/jQuery-Mapael-1.1.0/examples1.html) page with an update trigger that works fine. Now I want to move this to my real application php page, and it doesn't work! Please [take a look here](https://budker.uni-mainz.de/gnome/gnome/plot_index_new.php).

The annoying part is that the console of my Browser doesn't show any errors! How can I debug this problem when I don't see any errors? Please assist!

If you require any additional information, please ask. Thanks for any efforts.

PS: Please ignore the bad styling that the script and css code is in body. I'll fix this once this issue is resolved. I don't think it's the issue, since the example page that works is exactly the same and doesn't have this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, take a note that you're using different versions of Maphael:

- on the page where it works, version is 1.1.0,
- on your page it is 2.0.0-dev.

Second, after setting a breakpoint at the "onUpdateEvent" method of Maphael (line 876), it just seems that event data just doesn't get passed into the handler.

Does the "update" event have the same signature for Maphael/Raphael 1.x and 2.x? This is the place you should look at.

**Update**: I took a look at the 2.0.0-dev internals, and it seems your update code should be something like this:

```
var updatedOptions = {'areas': {}, 'plots' : {},
    // add some new plots ...
    newPlots: {
        "Dijon" : {
            latitude : 47.323056,
            longitude : 5.041944
        }
    },
    animDuration : 1000
};

$(".mapcontainer").trigger('update', updatedOptions);
```

(last line may be:

```
$(".mapcontainer").trigger('update', [updatedOptions]);
```

)

Please check if it helps (though I'd recomment you to switch to a stable 1.1.0 release of Maphael).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try downgrading now... I didn't realize the repo's master branch is version 2.0-dev... That's weird!

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist using master branch (instead of a separate branch) for development is usual for many projects, unfortunately. On Github, you should always go to "releases" page and download the latest stable one: https://github.com/neveldo/jQuery-Mapael/releases

Comment: It worked after downgrading to 1.1.0 through the tag 1.1.0! Thank you very much!